# Вывод значений ключей при получении нужного json

Tags: python

Делаю get запрос

```
res = requests.request("GET", 'example.com', headers={'local':'ru'})
```

Cервер может  прислать один из этих json

```
{
  "code": 1,
  "result": {
    "code": 10000,
    "List": [
      {
        "Id": "34",
        "local": {
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "35",
        "local": {
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

или

```
{
  "msg": "server error",
  "code": 500
}
```

После делаю вывод

```
print('Disconnect', if res.json()["code"] == 500 else 'Active')
```

Как добавить к статусу  "Active" значения ключей  "Id": "35", "34" в одной строке

Чтобы в итоге выводы были такими:

`Disconnect` или `Active | 35, 34`

Comment: У вас json не корректный в частности  "List". скорее всего должен быть  {"List": [{ "Id": "35"}, {"Id": "34"}]} ?

Comment: `else f'Active | {",".join(x["Id"] for x in res.json()["result"]["List"])}'` как-то так, если я правильно понял и эти `Id` у вас в разных элементах списка всё же

Comment: @Cергей Ш исправил json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё как я и написал в комментарии, вот проверка:

```py
def func(json_):
    print('Disconnect' if json_["code"] == 500 
          else f'Active | {",".join(x["Id"] for x in json_["result"]["List"])}')
    
func({
  "msg": "server error",
  "code": 500
})

func({
  "code": 1,
  "result": {
    "code": 10000,
    "List": [
      {
        "Id": "34",
        "local": {
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "35",
        "local": {
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Вывод:

```
Disconnect
Active | 34,35
```

Comment: Я в своем скрипте заменил  последнюю строку  для вывода на вашу, при выполнении ошибка: NameError: name 'json_' is not defined

Comment: print('Disconnect' if json_["code"] == 500 
          else f'Active | {",".join(x["Id"] for x in json_["result"]["List"])}')

Comment: Если напрямую менять хотите - возьмите строку из моего комментария, а не из ответа. В ответе же на функцию переделано.

Comment: Спасибо, Большое работает!